# How can I pass the array object?

Tags: c++

I am creating a structure as a data type What i basically want is to store the data which is line co-ordinates but when i pass two lines to find their distance and in arguments I pass the element of an array which is simple and the receiving argument is * how to resolve it.

This is the structure.

```
struct line_coordinates{
double x1,y1,x2,y2;
};
```

Here I am creating the array of a structure
    line_coordinates* array_line;
Now calling the getdistance() and passing arguments

```
void initlize(vector<Vec2f> line1){
lines=line1;
array_line=new line_coordinates[lines.size()];
cout<<getdistance(array_line[0],array_line[1]);


double getdistance(line_coordinates *line1,line_coordinates *line2 )
{

 double midpointx1,midpointy1,midpointx2,midpointy2;
 midpointx1 =((line1->x1+line1->x2)/2);
 midpointy1=((line1->y1+line1->y2)/2);

 midpointx2 =((line2->x1+line2->x2)/2);
 midpointy2=((line2->y1+line2->y2)/2);
 double dist = sqrt(pow(midpointx2 - midpointx1, 2) + pow(midpointy2 - midpointy1, 2));
return dist;
}
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow. Some problems: one: please use `std::vector<line_coordinates>`; two: unless you *need* a copy of `line1` to `initialize`, consider passing it by reference (`vector<Vec2f>& line1`) or const reference (`const vector<Vec2f>& line1`), whichever is the case; three: please provide a [short, self-contained and compilable example](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates what is your doubt, you really didn't present an answerable question...

Comment: My main concern was with passing the arrays element in to the getdistance() which is receiving it as *pointer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see, `array_line` is of type `line_coordinates*`, that means that `array_line[i]` is of a type convertible to `line_coordinates const&`, which means that you should pass it by reference or by value instead:

```
double getdistance(line_coordinates const& line1,line_coordinates const& line2)
//                                  ^^^^^^                        ^^^^^^
```

Oh and by the way, please use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: double getdistance(line_coordinates line1,line_coordinates line2){midpointx1 =((line1.x1+line1.x2)/2);
    }
changing code in this form help to resolve the problem.